# How to get intersection between two different faces of two different non indexed buffergeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, intersection, raycasting, face

How to intersect non indexed buffer geometry? I want to detect intersection between two defferent faces of two different non indexed buffergeometry. I set ray from middle of each faces, but raycaster don`t work with non indexed geometry.

I want to see result like this: 
[image]

Thank you very much!

**my code**

---

```
var box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.toNonIndexed(), material);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var intersects = [];

var pos = box.geometry.attributes.position;
var ori = new THREE.Vector3();
var dir = new THREE.Vector3();

var a = new THREE.Vector3(),
  b = new THREE.Vector3(),
  c = new THREE.Vector3(),
  tri = new THREE.Triangle();



var faces = pos.count / 3;
for (let i = 0; i < faces; i++) {
  a.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i * 3 + 0);
  b.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i * 3 + 1);
  c.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i * 3 + 2);
  tri.set(a, b, c);
  tri.getMidpoint(ori);
  tri.getNormal(dir)
  // scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(raycaster.ray.direction, raycaster.ray.origin, 30, 0xff0000));
  raycaster.set(ori, dir);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(box, true);

  if (intersects.length > 0) {

    console.log(intersects[0]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Seems you need to comment that line too: `raycaster.ray.origin, 30, 0xff0000));`

Comment: Thank you for your replying! I mistaked when copied code from my project. This line commented and don`t use

Comment: @ArkadiyVinkovskiy (1) Try calling `scene.updateMatrixWorld()` prior to raycasting. (2) You are raycasting `box` against itself. Add a different box.

Comment: Hi @WestLangley! Thank you! I converted my object to indexed geometry and set `scene.updateMatrixWorld()` all works very well but how i can check intersection in all objects that adding on scene? The main idea of ray cast is to blocked occupied side of box. If i click on side of box, new box appear on scene. You can see this in my project: https://alovert.ru

Comment: @WestLangley i load new object on scene by same function. And in this function i check intersection. Maybe problem in this.
**Simplified code:** https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqtIFlFVWz4MhNhoQ26CDkMJScPZXw

Comment: (1) Do not call `updateMatrixWorld()` for each face! Call it only once. I suggest you use the debugger to step through your code. I can't debug it for you. (2) `raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);` -- "Objects", with an "s".

Comment: Ok, i try it. Much thanks !